# What does "cast gloom" mean?

Tags: verbs

There is a chess player called Aron Nimzowitsch who has this famous quote: “The isolated Pawn casts gloom over the entire chessboard.”

I don't know what the casts gloom part means, so I don't understand what it means and I play chess a lot.

Comment: Have you looked up the individual words?

Comment: It is very similar to [**cast a shadow over**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cast+a+shadow+over). Although the gloom is an effect on the player really, not the board, as the chess set itself does not have emotion.

Comment: Hi @Cascabel I know what gloom means and I had an intuitive definition of cast because I'm a programmer (type casting), and I play MMORPG (cast a spell), so I didn't before, now you said it I did and it clarifies it. Thanks for the obvious suggestion that I overlooked.

Comment: It also goes to common words like _broadcast_, but many people have lost sight of the original meaning....

Comment: I see you point @WeatherVane now that I think I understand the quote, I believe he's talking about the importance of pawn structure.

Comment: @newbie: I'm guessing from your final sentence that *you* will know enough to say whether or not it's likely that a game on a board with an isolated pawn will be boring / poor quality / over too quickly or otherwise "defective" from *everyone's* perspective (both players *and* any audience).

Comment: Yes @FumbleFingers I definitely agree with you on that one

Comment: Actually, I haven't played chess in years (decades, perhaps). But I kinda remember becoming aware at some point that I shouldn't use the *en passant* move as often as I did. I often did it because I thought it was "exotic" and thus "clever", but in practice it was as likely as not to just mess up my pawn structure and put me at a disadvantage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a *passable* chess player, but I'm not quite sure why an isolated pawn would "cast gloom" on the game. Whatever - here's my guess.

I'm assuming that the fact of the gloom being explicitly cast over the ***board***, rather than one or other of the ***players*** means that there's no automatic link between which player has an isolated pawn and which player will win the game.

I think the "chessboard with isolated pawn" is similar to the situation on a snooker table where the balls are in such a position that no "positive" shot can be made by either player, so they just take turns moving the cue-ball as little as possible, to avoid giving the *other* player a chance to go for a pot.

When that happens in snooker, the players often agree to a "**re-rack**" (start the game again), but from what I know of chess you can't do that there (both players would have to agree to call it a draw, which is a recorded "game outcome").

So really, the "gloom" in OP's context is as much for the *spectators* as the players. In some way that I don't know enough to explain, the fact of that isolated pawn means the game is likely to be ***boring*** (or otherwise of poor quality).

Comment: I like the context you gave and the example. However as anything in chess depends on the context, an isolated pawn on an ending is one thing and depends a lot on what pieces the other player has. But I'm guessing that Aron meant that in the opening it probably will be something that the opponent will try to take advantage of by attacking it with as many pieces as he/she can, resulting in what it COULD be a low quality game. Maybe the quote is not as good as I thought it was xD
I believe he is talking mostly about the importance of pawn structure, in a sort of poetic way.

Comment: I don't get that. Are you saying you think it's clear-cut that a player with an isolated pawn is likely to lose the game? If so then I can see how *that* player might be gloomy, but surely by implication the *other* player would be as happy as Larry! In which case the total net position is simply "neutral", not "gloomy".

Comment: ...OR are you saying that a chess writer / analyst (who doesn't necessarily care *who* wins the game) would think that a game with an isolated pawn is somehow unlikely to be an interesting one for him to work through?

Comment: When [researching](https://chess-teacher.com/how-to-play-with-or-against-isolated-pawn/) the quote, I found another: “He who fears the isolated queen’s pawn should give up chess” – Siegbert Tarrasch.

Comment: I deplore the closure of this question. The discussion - which veered too easily into secondary speculative detail of chess play - shows it to have been relevant to context, usage and meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I meant that in the middlegame an isolated pawn will be punished by his opponent, and that pawn structure is key in a chess game

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't want to dive into a chess discussion, but actually Tarrasch is from the same school as Aron Nimzowitsch and was by no means better than him. In that time Capablanca dominated the chess world for many years, scared or no not about an isolated pawn, no matter how much the prepped they would dramatically lose against him

Comment: @FumbleFingers I believe the second option is more like what I think the quote means. Very unlikely you will see in the top level isolated pawns in the opening... chess sites are amazing now, lichess.org is totally free and chess.com is not expensive, both are great and it seems you do like it a lot. I say this because you said you haven't played in years.